# Could you please let me know the Maven dependency for newAPIHadoopRDD

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Could you please let me know the Maven dependency for newAPIHadoopRDD. My code is:

```
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD = ctx.newAPIHadoopRDD(
                        conf,
                        TextInputFormat.class,,
                        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
                        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you also post the actual code.?

Comment: I have added the maven dependencies list. If you could provide the whole code, i could help you better.

Comment: Does it resovle your error..

Comment: If it resolved ur issue, u cud accept it as resolution

Comment: @Bhaskar it looks like the answer resolved your problem. If this is the case, mark the answer as accepted, by clicking on the tick-mark to make it green (see the image in this page http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/279178 )

Answer (score 0):

You are using TextInputFormat. It has to be TableInputFormat.
and the conf you have used, is it SparkConf or org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.?

Maven Dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop-compat</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- HBase dependencies Start -->
```

Code:

```
Configuration hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "table1");

JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> routerRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
```